# How to replace all cursor appearances within a QML program?

Tags: qt, cursor, qml

I'm working on a game that uses QML for its UI.

I would like to replace all cursors appearances with cursor-images that are more fitting to the game style (e.g. pointing skeleton hand instead of the normal `Qt::ArrowCursor`).

Calling `QGuiApplication::setOverrideCursor()` seams **not** to be a practical solution as I can not "overwrite" each `MouseArea` to call may `replaceCursor()` magic-global-function. For example the change column with cursor within a `TableView` is currently impossible for me to manipulate.

To me the most practical solution would be to replace the appearance of all cursors but leaf Qt with the tasks to correctly choose the cursor style.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You can still use `QGuiApplication::setOverrideCursor()` to decorate your mouse areas. It works like a stack, you can set and then restore cursors, so you begin with setting an initial cursor from `main.cpp`, and then you use an "overloaded" `MouseArea` which sets its cursor using `setOverrideCursor()` as well, instead of using the QML functionality.

For example:

```
onContainsMouseChanged: {
  if (containsMouse) Sys.setOverrideCursor(yourCursortype)
  else Sys.restoreOverrideCursor()
}
```

Of course, that means you will have to create an auxiliary object that will call those functions from C++, and expose it to QML so it can be called from there.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I'm currently doing. But I can only manipulate `MouseAreas` in my own QML code. If they are hidden away and can not even be manipulated via delegate overwrite  this trick does not work.
In my case the change width cursor for the column width of a TableView.

Comment: You can overlay stick components with a disabled mouse area that will still do the trick to toggle the cursor. It actually sounds like a bug, hence this report, but it might do the trick for you. https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-56287